# Remember id username and password from mysql

Tags: php

Im trying to learn php and i need some help. How can i set a "id" from mysql in a session? so $_SESSION['id'] will work. I will be very thankful if someone could help me :-)

```html
<?php
session_start();

?>

<?php

if(isset($_POST["navn"]) && isset($_POST["passord"])){
    // Connect to mySQL
    include "include/config.php"

    // Query the person
    $sql = $conn->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE navn='$navn' AND password='$passord' LIMIT 1");

    // Make sure person exists
    $existCount = $sql->rowCount();

    // Evaluate the count
    if($existCount == 1){
        while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $id = $row["id"];
        }
        $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
        $_SESSION["user"] = $user;
        $_SESSION["password"] = $password;
        header("location:index.php");
        exit();
    }else{
        echo"Login details incorrect, try again <a href='index.php'>Click here</a>";
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This should just work?

Comment: Redirection might not work. There is a whitespace when you close the php tag below the `session_start();`

Comment: `$navn` and `$passord` is not set.

Comment: I know youre learning.  But please do some research on prepared statements and sql injection.  Its worth learning that from the ground up.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting data from the POST request which you don't actually use
`isset($_POST["navn"]) && isset($_POST["passord"])`

Then you try to use undefined variables 
`navn='$navn' AND password='$passord'`

To fix. Just set your variables from the POST request.

```
$navn = $_POST["navn"];
$passord = $_POST["passord"];
```

That should fix it.